# Adding Paypal Pay Now button in Android app

Tags: android

This may have been asked before but I cannot find a definitive answer

I am currently using Google in app billing for my application and users are asking me if they can use Paypal.

Is it against the market policy if I add a Paypal Buy now button to my payment screen which opens a URL in a webview and goes to Paypal.com ? ….

The app is published in the Android Market

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should not use other payment system because...

"Google has been pressuring applications and mobile game developers to use its costlier in-house payment service, Google Wallet for quite some time. Now Google warned several developers in recent months that if they continued to use other payment methods — such as PayPal, Zong and Boku — [their apps would be removed from Google Play](http://www.reuters.com/article/2012/03/08/us-google-idUSBRE8271CJ20120308). The move is seen as a way to cut costs for Google by using their own system."

Comment: Keep in mind that Google will take 30% off the top of your in-app billing profits.

Answer (score 2):

Even if it's not against to T&C, it's not a good practice. Google is trying to do the opposite: everything should be with their payment solution, so your app's users see something that they already know.

However did you consider opening a webpage and from there doing the paypal payment? That probably would not be against T&C

Answer (score -2):

No way, it should be violation of T&C. Google is not Evil.